# Is there a Facebook Streaming API similar to the Twitter Streaming API (other that the Real-Time API)

Tags: .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time

**Is there a Facebook Streaming API similar to the Twitter Streaming API (other that the Real-Time API)**

The question is simply in the title. I would like to somehow get real-time user interactions from Facebook in a similar fashion to the Twitter API... I would like to accomplish this with an access_token from my authorized users (e.g. I don't want to use the Javascript API).

Comment: well..... there should be ;)